# C++ call std::list<my_type> of objects instead of C linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Can this be made more C++ a like with `std::list` or something so the `Clink` class is not needed?

I have a dynamic list of objects, and the number of them could change during runtime.

The expected output in no specific order. As an example 'Cb' runs before 'Ca':

```
link-contructed
Ca-contructed
Cb-contructed
Cb-run
Ca-run
Ca-destructed
Cb-destructed
link-destructed
```

I would like the program to be more C++ like with `std::list` or something. I have looked at [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) but can not really see how it should be used. All examples I could find is about `std::list<int>`. My `Ctask` needs to have `next` in it and `Clink` needs to know which objects is used. Not so generic. Here is the mixed C/C++ program which does the expected:

```
/*
vim: ts=4 :
g++ -lstdc++ -o linked linked.cpp && ./linked
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Ctask {
public:
    Ctask *next = NULL;
    Ctask(void) {}
    virtual ~Ctask(void) {}
    virtual void run(void) = 0;
};

/* --------------------------------- */

class Clink {
public:
    Clink(void) {
        cout << "link-contructed" << endl;
    }
    ~Clink(void) {
        Ctask *temp;
        while (temp = head) {
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        cout << "link-destructed" << endl;
    }
    void run(void) {
        Ctask *temp = head;
        while (temp) {
            temp->run();
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    void add(Ctask *newnode) {
        if (tail)
            tail->next = newnode;
        else
            head = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
    }
private:
    Ctask *head = NULL;
    Ctask *tail = NULL;
};

/* --------------------------------- */

class Ca: public Ctask {
public:
    Ca(void) {
        cout << "Ca-contructed" << endl;
    }
    ~Ca(void) {
        cout << "Ca-destructed" << endl;
    }
    void run(void) {
        cout << "Ca-run" << endl;
    }
};

class Cb: public Ctask {
public:
    Cb(void) {
        cout << "Cb-contructed" << endl;
    }
    ~Cb(void) {
        cout << "Cb-destructed" << endl;
    }
    void run(void) {
        cout << "Cb-run" << endl;
    }
};

/* --------------------------------- */

int main(void) {
    Clink link;
    link.add((Ctask *)new Ca());
    link.add((Ctask *)new Cb());
    link.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it required that the destruction of elements happen in a specified order? If yes, I might have bad news for you.

Comment: @BenSteffan, all implementations I know of do linear destruction from the start. It is not guaranteed by the standard. Am I looking in the wrong way? (Not author of the question)

Comment: @BenSteffan `Specified order` would be best but unordered would be very useful.

Comment: @Incomputable Well that's the issue. In theory, an implementation might have a different order (although the most common implementations don't).

Comment: @BenSteffan, all of the operations on the objects have a side effect, so at least destructions are not interleaved. Now I believe that destruction must happen from either end, but that's a pure speculation. If the member functions wouldn't have side effects, even the non-interleave guarantee would be off, from my parsing through [sequences] part of the C++17 draft. I guess the only solution is to do undefined inheritance from list and define custom destructor.

Comment: @Incomputable That or ensuring the destruction order by manually removing element by element from the container. Both seem like really ugly hacks.

Comment: @BenSteffan I have dropped the required ordered list as it is only a theoretical speed improvement.
I tried to remove `delete temp;` (manually destruction of Ctask's) but then the Ctask's did not get a destructor notification. It might be because I have made them as pointers, which was required for the C linked list. If the construction was made like `link.add(new Ca());` the destructor might be able to work automatically but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Note that `td::forward_list<std::function<void()>>` (of any other container storing captured closures) would probably do as well for this particular design, saving you some work of defining basic abstract class—with a list implementation detail inside!—and its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answer and the comments from @user673679, with some modifications:

- Removing `using namespace std`.
- Using `unique_ptr` to transparently handle object allocation and deallocation. Remember to create items with [`make_unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr/22571331#22571331).
- `forward_list` is just fine for a FIFO queue.

Note that I don't use a range-based for loop because I only iterate the list once (run function and remove element).

```
#include "ctask.h" // Ctask, Ca and Cb definitions
#include <forward_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

class TaskQueue {
public:
   TaskQueue() :
     _tasks(),
     _last( _tasks.before_begin() )
   {
   }

   ~TaskQueue() = default;

   void add( std::unique_ptr<Ctask>&& t ) {
     _last = _tasks.insert_after( _last, std::move(t) );
   }

   void run_all() {
     task_list::iterator prev = _tasks.before_begin();
     task_list::iterator curr = _tasks.begin();
     while( curr != _tasks.end() ) {
        (*curr)->run();
        curr = _tasks.erase_after(prev);
     }
     _last = prev;
   }

private:
   typedef std::forward_list<std::unique_ptr<Ctask>> task_list;
   task_list           _tasks;
   task_list::iterator _last;
};

int main(void) {
    TaskQueue queue;
    queue.add(std::make_unique<Ca>());
    queue.add(std::make_unique<Cb>());
    queue.run_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I realized that you can make `run_all` more readable since you are basically removing all the elements from the queue, so that the while loop doesn't actually depend on `_last` value. The simplified function would be:

```
   void TaskQueue::run_all() {
     while( !_tasks.empty() ) {
        _tasks.front()->run();
        _tasks.pop_front();
     }
     _last = _tasks.before_begin();
   }
```

Comment: I like the encapsulation of TaskQueue and `run_all()`. It was actually my next question: How to make the `main` more readable. Thanks.

Comment: You could make `TaskQueue` more efficient by making the list intrusive, so that you only need to dereference 1 pointer (next) instead of two (next and task data). In this case, `Ctask` would contain a member `list_hook` that will contain the pointer to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at a lot of `std::list` examples I came up with this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Ctask {
public:
    Ctask(void) {}
    virtual ~Ctask(void) {}
    virtual void run(void) = 0;
};

/* --------------------------------- */

class Ca: public Ctask {
public:
    Ca(void) {
        cout << "Ca-contructed" << endl;
    }
    ~Ca(void) {
        cout << "Ca-destructed" << endl;
    }
    void run(void) {
        cout << "Ca-run" << endl;
    }
};

class Cb: public Ctask {
public:
    Cb(void) {
        cout << "Cb-contructed" << endl;
    }
    ~Cb(void) {
        cout << "Cb-destructed" << endl;
    }
    void run(void) {
        cout << "Cb-run" << endl;
    }
};

/* --------------------------------- */

int main(void) {
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Ctask>> taskList;
    taskList.push_back(std::make_unique<Ca>());
    taskList.push_back(std::make_unique<Cb>());
    for (auto& t : taskList)
        t->run();
    return 0;
}
```

1. What would be a more precise question to the problem?
2. Is this the *correct* & *un-ugly* way to do it?
3. Can `(*tl)->run()` be written *nicer*?
4. Can `delete (*tl)` be handled differently and should one avoid to directly call `delete`?

Comment: 2. Pretty much. 3. A range-based for loop: `for (auto& t : taskList) t->run();` 4. Change the list to a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Ctask>>` so the list owns the tasks, and there would be no need to do manual deletion.

Comment: The *technically correct* implementation would be with a `forward_list`, where you remove items from the head and save an iterator to the tail, which is updated after every insertion. This would be a good step if you plan to insert and remove items from the list concurrently (parallel creation and execution).

Comment: @user673679 Wow, that `main` code became rather short. I guess it can not be shorter.